# Let $W$ = {($x,y,z$) : $y=0$, $z=0$} be subset of $R^3$. Is $W$ a subspace of $R^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W$ = {($x,y,z$) : $y=0$, $z=0$} be subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Is $W$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

I really don't like this topic. Could you help me How I can solve this simple problem? Thanks in advance for your help and sorry for my English.

Comment: If the sum of two elements from $W,$ and any constant multiple of an element are again elements of $W,$ it is a subspace.

Comment: Alternatively, $W$ is the kernel of the linear map $L:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $L(x,y,z)=(y,z)$, and so, it is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: really thanks for your idea. whatever I solve any question in this topic, the solution is always subspace. is not there any exception that is not in this subspace? I don't know maybe my language is different, the translation of terminology is not enough to understand, I didn't get this simple topic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ as an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space. It contains the zero vector. It is closed under vector addition, since any two vector added is another vector with $y=0$ and $z=0$. It is closed under scalar multiplication, since multiply by any scalar is a vector with $y=0$ and $z=0$.

Comment: thanks really for your comment. for x value what can I write in the vector W? and this notation is true? W= W1(x1,y1,z1)+W2(x2,y2,z2) = (x1,0,0)+(x2,0,0)=(x1+x2,0,0)

Comment: @bradd yes what you wrote is true

Answer (score 0):

The other comments and answers are complete enough, so I will just add something more on the geometric interpretation. Since $(x,y,z)$ in $W$ must have $y=z=0$, then $(x,y,z) = (x,0,0) = x(1,0,0)$, so $W$ is the line in $\mathbb R^3$ generated by $(1,0,0)$.